# T-SQL : Slicing time periods by related time periods

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, gaps-and-islands

Consider the following table that gives the validity dates for which an `Item` is associated to something called a `Demand_Unit`, and a certain `Market` :

| Item_ID | Start_Date | End_Date | Demand_Unit | Market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2020-06-01 | 2020-09-30 | A | GREECE |
| X | 2020-11-01 | 2021-01-01 | A | BELGIUM |
| X | 2021-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | A | USA |
| Y | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | B | PORTUGAL |
| Y | 2021-02-01 | 2021-06-07 | B | FRANCE |
| Y | 2021-06-07 | 2022-01-03 | B | ITALY |
| Y | 2022-01-03 | 2023-12-31 | B | SPAIN |
| Y | 2024-01-01 | 2025-12-31 | B | UKRAINE |
| Z | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 | C | USA |
| W | 2021-02-01 | 2021-05-30 | D | SWEDEN |
| W | 2023-12-31 | 2025-05-30 | D | DANEMARK |
| U | 2021-01-04 | 2022-02-07 | E | TUNISIA |
| U | 2022-02-07 | 2025-01-05 | (null) | MOROCCO |

> Important note:
> You can never have overlapping dates because basically when one Market closes another opens. But it is possible to have non-contiguous periods (like for `Item` X for example)

Now consider the following table that gives the `Classification`s of a `Demand_Unit` throughout time:

| Demand_Unit | Start_Date | End_Date | Classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05 | N+ |
| A | 2021-04-05 | 2023-12-31 | K- |
| B | 2021-03-08 | 2021-07-26 | N+ |
| B | 2021-07-26 | 2022-11-30 | L- |
| C | 2021-01-01 | 2023-12-31 | N- |
| D | 2021-06-01 | 2023-12-31 | K+ |
| E | 2021-08-02 | 2022-01-03 | N+ |
| E | 2022-01-03 | 2025-01-06 | C- |

> Important note:
> You can only have contiguous periods here. This table is extracted from a Slowly changing dimension.

The goal is to 'slice' the first table to associate to each `Item` its `Classification`, while taking into account the time periods. The result should look like this:

| Item_ID | Demand_Unit | Market | Item_Classification_Dt_Begin | Item_Classification_Dt_End | Item_Classification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U | E | TUNISIA | 2021-01-04 | 2021-08-02 | (null) |
| U | E | TUNISIA | 2021-08-02 | 2022-01-03 | N+ |
| U | E | TUNISIA | 2022-01-03 | 2022-02-07 | C- |
| U | (null) | MOROCCO | 2022-02-07 | 2025-01-05 | (null) |
| W | D | SWEDEN | 2021-02-01 | 2021-05-30 | (null) |
| W | D | DANEMARK | 2023-12-31 | 2023-12-31 | K+ |
| W | D | DANEMARK | 2023-12-31 | 2025-05-30 | (null) |
| X | A | GREECE | 2020-06-01 | 2020-09-30 | (null) |
| X | A | BELGIUM | 2020-11-01 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| X | A | USA | 2021-01-01 | 2021-04-05 | N+ |
| X | A | USA | 2021-04-05 | 2023-12-31 | K- |
| Y | B | PORTUGAL | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 | (null) |
| Y | B | FRANCE | 2021-02-01 | 2021-03-08 | (null) |
| Y | B | FRANCE | 2021-03-08 | 2021-06-07 | N+ |
| Y | B | ITALY | 2021-06-07 | 2021-07-26 | N+ |
| Y | B | ITALY | 2021-07-26 | 2022-01-03 | L- |
| Y | B | SPAIN | 2022-01-03 | 2022-11-30 | L- |
| Y | B | SPAIN | 2022-11-30 | 2023-12-31 | (null) |
| Y | B | UKRAINE | 2024-01-01 | 2025-12-31 | (null) |
| Z | C | USA | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 | (null) |
| Z | C | USA | 2021-05-01 | 2021-06-30 | N- |

These are some examples with 'tricky' cases (Items X and Y) and a 'simple' case (Item Z) which has its dates completely included in the classifications period, + other cases to try and test possibilities I could think of...

I'm working on a solution that uses `LAG()` `LEAD()` and a three-part `UNION`, but I'm afraid I'm forgetting something and the original table has hundreds of thousands of rows.

I'm not trying to have someone do my work here, I would just like your opinions on how should this be properly done.
Here's my solution so far, it looks like it works but I don't find it elegant and I'm sure the second and third `UNION` block can be simplified, but I just can't see straight anymore.

```
;WITH CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD AS
(
SELECT
Demand_Unit
,Start_Date
,End_Date
,Classification
,LAG(End_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Demand_Unit ORDER BY Start_Date)      AS LAGD
,LEAD(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Demand_Unit ORDER BY Start_Date )  AS LEADD
FROM Classifications
)
-- This first block handles Item periods that are not covered by classifications periods
-- and/or the NULL classif portion of Item periods that are partially covered by classifications periods
SELECT  
T1.Item_ID
,T1.Demand_Unit 
,T1.Market
,CASE 
    WHEN T2.End_Date > T1.Start_Date
         AND T2.End_Date <= T1.End_Date
      THEN T2.End_Date
    ELSE T1.Start_Date 
END                            AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,CASE
    WHEN T2.Start_Date > T1.Start_Date
         AND T2.Start_Date <= T1.End_Date
      THEN T2.Start_Date
    ELSE T1.End_Date
END                            AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,NULL                          AS Item_Classification
FROM Items T1
INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD T2
    ON T1.Demand_Unit = T2.Demand_Unit
    AND ( 
            (
             LAGD IS NULL 
             AND T1.Start_Date < T2.Start_Date 
            )
            OR
            (
             LEADD IS NULL
             AND T1.End_Date > T2.End_Date
            )
        )

UNION
-- The following block handles Items periods that are (at least partially) 
-- contained within the Classification period, and checks which DT_BEGIN to use
SELECT
T1.Item_ID
,T1.Demand_Unit 
,T1.Market
,CASE 
     WHEN T1.Start_Date < T2.Start_Date THEN T2.Start_Date 
    ELSE T1.Start_Date
 END                           AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,T1.End_Date                   AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,T2.Classification             AS Item_Classification
FROM Items T1
INNER JOIN Classifications T2
    ON T1.Demand_Unit = T2.Demand_Unit
    AND T1.End_Date <= T2.End_Date
    AND T1.End_Date > T2.Start_Date

UNION
-- The following block handles Items periods that are (at least partially) 
-- contained within the Classification period, and checks which DT_END to use
SELECT
T1.Item_ID
,T1.Demand_Unit 
,T1.Market
,T1.Start_Date                 AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,CASE
      WHEN T1.End_Date > T2.End_Date THEN T2.End_Date
      ELSE T1.End_Date
END                            AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,T2.Classification             AS Item_Classification
FROM Items T1
INNER JOIN Classifications T2
    ON T1.Demand_Unit = T2.Demand_Unit
    AND T1.Start_Date < T2.End_Date
    AND T1.Start_Date >= T2.Start_Date

ORDER BY Item_ID, 4
```

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8b19f0/7/0)

Many thanks in advance

Edit : last minute fixes in my solution

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your working query?

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle - I believe the last row inserted into `Classificaitons` should be for C, not A.

Comment: @dwhitemv : Done, I just don't find my solution elegant and didn't want to influence other answers.

Comment: @bbaird you were right, thank you ! fixed the fiddle

Comment: I tagged this with [tag:gaps-and-islands] since it seems like an interesting reverse case of putting the gaps back in. Take a look at the tagged posts for other tactics. Your strategy looks sound. Minor quibbles would be to use GREATEST() and LEAST() instead of a couple of CASEs and see if UNION ALL would work instead of the deduped UNION.

Comment: Hello @dwhitemv, thank you, hopefully someone will have a more elegant solution. I looked around other posts, didn't find any that address this kind of problem. UNION is necessary because when Items rows are completely within a Classif periods, they match on the two UNION blocks, so deduplication is necessary (look at example of Item "Z" I believe).

Comment: The previous solution does not work for some cases that I added to the examples (cf. Item U and a few added rows for Item B). Proposing a new solution that currently works in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution works better for edge cases. It takes advantage of the fact that

> You can only have contiguous periods in the Classifications table

.

```
;WITH CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD AS
(
SELECT
Demand_Unit
,Start_Date
,End_Date
,Classification
,LAG(End_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Demand_Unit ORDER BY Start_Date)    AS LAGD
,LEAD(Start_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Demand_Unit ORDER BY Start_Date )    AS LEADD
FROM Classifications
)
,Items_Numbered AS
(
SELECT
Item_ID
,Start_Date
,End_Date
,Demand_Unit
,Market
FROM Items
)
, Slices AS 
(
-- The following block takes care of Item periods that starts before the First Classif 
-- period (or finishes after the Last CLassif period), and it specifies NULL Classif
SELECT 
I1.Item_ID
,I1.Demand_Unit 
,I1.Market
,CASE
   WHEN C1.Demand_Unit IS NULL THEN I1.Start_Date
   WHEN C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date AND I1.Start_Date >= C1.Start_Date THEN C1.End_Date
   ELSE I1.Start_Date                 
 END                           AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,CASE
   WHEN C1.Demand_Unit IS NULL THEN I1.End_Date
   WHEN C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date AND I1.Start_Date >= C1.Start_Date THEN I1.End_Date
   --AND I1.Start_Date >= C1.Start_Date
   ELSE C1.Start_Date
 END                           AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(3))                          AS Item_Classification
FROM Items_Numbered I1
INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD C1 
    ON I1.Demand_Unit = C1.Demand_Unit
    AND ( 
      (C1.Start_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.Start_Date < I1.End_Date AND LAGD IS NULL)
      OR
      (C1.End_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date AND LEADD IS NULL)
    )

UNION ALL
--The following block basically takes care of all items periods that partially overlap Classif periods
SELECT
I1.Item_ID
,I1.Demand_Unit 
,I1.Market
,CASE
   WHEN C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date AND I1.Start_Date >= C1.Start_Date THEN I1.Start_Date
   ELSE C1.Start_Date                 
 END                           AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,CASE
   WHEN C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date THEN C1.End_Date
   ELSE I1.End_Date
 END                           AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,C1.Classification             AS Item_Classification
FROM Items_Numbered I1
INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD C1 
    ON I1.Demand_Unit = C1.Demand_Unit
    AND ( 
      (C1.Start_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.Start_Date < I1.End_Date)
      OR
      (C1.End_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date)
    )

UNION ALL

-- The following block takes care of Item periods that are completely included inside a Classif period
SELECT  
I1.Item_ID
,I1.Demand_Unit 
,I1.Market
,I1.Start_Date                 AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,I1.End_Date                   AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,C1.Classification             AS Item_Classification
FROM Items_Numbered I1
INNER JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD C1 
    ON I1.Demand_Unit = C1.Demand_Unit
    AND I1.Start_Date >= C1.Start_Date 
    AND I1.End_Date < C1.End_Date

)

SELECT
Item_ID,
Demand_Unit,
Market,
Item_Classification_Dt_Begin,
Item_Classification_Dt_End,
MAX(Item_Classification) AS Item_Classification
FROM Slices
GROUP BY 
Item_ID,
Demand_Unit,
Market,
Item_Classification_Dt_Begin,
Item_Classification_Dt_End

UNION ALL
--The following block takes care of all the Item periods that have no match with the classifs
--(either because the Item is not linked to a DU, or because there is no Classif for the whole time period)
-- Since we used INNER JOIN in the previous CTE, we must include these rows back in this block...
SELECT
I1.Item_ID
,I1.Demand_Unit 
,I1.Market
,I1.Start_Date AS Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
,I1.End_Date  AS Item_Classification_Dt_End
,NULL            AS Item_Classification
FROM Items_Numbered I1
LEFT JOIN CLASSIFICATIONS_LAG_LEAD C1 
    ON I1.Demand_Unit = C1.Demand_Unit
    AND ( 
      (C1.Start_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.Start_Date < I1.End_Date)
      OR
      (C1.End_Date >= I1.Start_Date AND C1.End_Date < I1.End_Date)
    )
WHERE C1.Demand_Unit IS NULL

ORDER BY Item_ID, Item_Classification_Dt_Begin
```